# Resilience4j never throws MaxRetriesExceededException

Tags: java, spring-boot, resilience4j

I have a service that makes a rest api call which throws a 503 server exception for reproducing a defect.

This is the retry config i'm using:

```
  maxAttempts: 5
  waitDuration: 2s
  failAfterMaxAttempts: true
  retryExceptionPredicate: GenericRetryOnResultPredicate
  resultPredicate: GenericRetryOnResultPredicate
```

My service call is annotated with @CircuitBreaker too.

The fallback method is invoked after maxAttempts but the exception is not MaxRetriesExceededException.

Resilience4j version: 2.0.2

I have two fallback methods one with MaxRetriesExceededException and other with Exception, although I get a CallNotPermittedException when the circuit is open the MaxRetriesExceededException is never received while the documentation states otherwise.

Anyone faced similar problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.